# HighCharts full width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im trying to make my rendered chart fill 100% of the parent div with no success. Is there any way I can remove the gap on the left and right sides?

http://jsfiddle.net/sKV9d/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        margin: 0,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
    },    

    series: [{
        data: [33,4,15,6,7,8, 73,2, 33,4,25],    

        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 17):

If you remove the options `width: 300, height: 200` like this:

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    margin: 0,
    defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
},    

...
```

it will fill automatically the container.

Comment: As highcharts doc said: 
An explicit width for the chart. By default (when null) the width is calculated from the offset width of the containing element. Defaults to null.  it works

Answer (score 17):

The issue is because of jquery UI. after rendering your chart call this code to reflow the chart. This fixed my problem

```
chart.reflow();
```

Comment: Some example when you created your chart elsewhere: `$("#chartDiv").highcharts().reflow();`

Comment: Just a heads up that I had a similar issue when rendering charts inside a React component's `componentDidMount`. Axis labels were overflowing the chart and were only partially visible until I added `chart.reflow()` as the last call in the method.

Comment: In Angular, I wrapped the chart initialization in a setTimeout which is called in the ngAfterViewInit lifecyclehook:  
`setTimeout( () => this.hcChart = Highcharts.chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, options ) );` 
Seems like if I wait a tick before rendering the chart, highcharts picks up the correct container size at initialization.

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

UPD:

1. remove width and height attributes.
2. add into .css the following code in order to adjust chart block to 100% of #container:

## chart { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

2a. another way is - in case if not possible to define container size during "design" time you can reflow chart after chart load (i.e. call chart.reflow(); ):

```
chart: {

    events: {
        load: function(event) {
        **event.target.reflow();**
      }
    }
},
```

See example http://jsfiddle.net/yfjLce3o/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11731250)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's not a full answer. I found another one, and I will add it as comment for author.

Comment: Does not look like 100% to me, there is a white space of 3px still there.

Answer (score 9):

Set `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to 0, see: http://jsfiddle.net/sKV9d/3/

Answer (score 7):

just simply add CSS

```
.highcharts-container{
  width: 100% !important;
}

.highcharts-root{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: this is work, but my tooltip become error couse this css

Answer (score 6):

The issue with Highcharts already reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5783).
To handle this we can do something like mentioned above.
I was also facing the same problem so I have solved it by using

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

after rendering my chart like :

```
this.chartData={
...     //some required data object to render chart
}

 Highcharts.stockChart('divContainerID', this.chartData, function (chart) {});
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
var height= $("#container").height();
var width= $("#container").width();

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        margin: 0,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
    },    

    series: [{
        data: [33,4,15,6,7,8, 73,2, 33,4,25],    

        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Still has the gaps unfortunately. The chart itself (svg) is full width, it just seems the data itself has a gap.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not provide `width` property to the chart, it should automatically get the width of the container.
So just remove the width from the chart and give the container `width: 100%` and that should work.

If you want a specific width, just change the container width to a specific size. The chart should still be 100% of that size.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKV9d/213/)

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        margin: 0,
        height: 200,
        defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [33,4,15,6,7,8, 73,2, 33,4,25],

        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use updateChart function and call chart.reflow() inside that function

```
scope.updatechart = function(){
     scope.chart.reflow();
}
```

call updatechart method every 30 seconds using any refresh mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and it is working very well:

chart-tab is div, and contains high chart div, so you first need to define two DIVs, first for containing the `chart('chart-container')`, and second the container of 'chart-container' which is 'chart-tab', then one library must be `added('resizesensor')` for adding the event for 'chart-tab' DIV on-change , and here is the function as follows:

```
    new ResizeSensor($('#chart-tab'), function(){ 
    if(chart){  
    var wid = document.getElementById('chart-tab').clientWidth;
        var hei = document.getElementById('chart-tab').clientWidth;
        chart.update({
            chart: {
            width: wid,
            height: hei
            }
        });

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of chart.update function from anywhere across your project.

```
   Highcharts.charts.forEach(function (chart) {
    chart.update({ chart: { width: some value } }, true, true, true);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a loading issue that caused the chart container to be too narrow. If you make use of jQuery then load your chart like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let chart = Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Angular only**:

if you are using **angular-highchart** library then remove style from your options and simple do this

```js
<highcharts-chart
    *ngFor="let stock of chartArray; let i = index"
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="'stockChart'"
    [options]="stock.chartOption"
    style="width: 100%; display: block"
  >
  </highcharts-chart>
```

**style="width: 100%; display: block"** here is the noticable part. Ignore the rest please

Answer (score -1):

For me using Angular it was solved by moving setting the option in ngAfterViewInit!