# Highcharts's width is not able to fill 100% of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'd like to fill the Highcharts to fill its width to 100% of its parent without any padding left/right.

I read [HighCharts full width issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330237/highcharts-full-width-issue) and tried set :`margin` `minPadding`  and `maxPadding` to 0 but does not work.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwNRGY) to demonstrate the problem

From the demo, the xAxis is to expand 100% of the container, and part of x categories value is not shown.

How can I setup the options to solve the problem?

Comment: your demo does not open to me

Comment: @smnbbrv ,  please check the updated link

Comment: You have spacingLeft and spacingRight of 15px. This is the reason why it's showing padding. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set min/max values as workaround.

```
xAxis:{
      type:'categories',
      min:0.49,
      max: categories.length - 1.49,
      categories: categories,
      minPadding:0,
      maxPadding:0,
      gridLineWidth:0,
      tickmarkPlacement: 'between',//仅适用于类别轴categories值时候，刻度线位于在类别名称的中心
      labels: {
          align:'center',
          y:-3,//垂直偏移
          style:{
              color:'white'
          }
      }
    },
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZWxwa

Comment: min works but max is not working, I still see the padding right. And also, would you please explain a little bit how it works? What does 0.49 means?

Comment: Fixed demo, should be -1.49 instead of -0.49

Comment: Would you please explain why it is 0.49? This works well at the demo page but not works very well at my application , will this be support at lower version?(In my real application, the categories's length is 15)

Comment: The rea is printed from middle of category. So you need to cut half of that category by setting min/max values.

Comment: my step of labels is set to 1(this is the default options of my util function) , and the fisrt and last label is cut half, how to solve this(I can override it with any thing I want, I tried null but no use)? check this:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwNRGY

Comment: Im not sure what you have cut, because in your demo all is pritned properly. Labels are moved inside, to avoid cut a text, is that incorrect?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwNRGY check the updated demo, and notice that the step is set to 1, and the problem occurs

Comment: Instead of step, you can use tickInterval as 1 (in xAxis), then all ticks are printed and labels are displayed properly.